How to debug tests in spring?
I have a spring boot project. Usually I run IDEA debugger on port 63344, set breakpoints, run
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:63344"
and my application connects to debugger without any problems.
I have some tests which can be runned with:
./mvnw test
I want to set breakpoints in my tests and debug them. How I can do it? Which flags I need to add to ./mvnw test command for JDB to connect to IDEA?

why not run just right click at the test file you want to debug in Intellij and select Debug {FooClass}  ?

@JAsgarov, If I will do it IntelliJ IDEA will run tests locally. In my case I want to run tests inside docker container.

You can try
./mvnw test -Dtest=TestClass.java#testMethod

with -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments being the same. More info:
https://dev.to/pavel_polivka/debugging-maven-tests-in-intellij-idea-c74

I runned tests with Dtest argument and IDEA still not stopped on my breakpoint.
